# Why does my mongoose validation callback return; TypeError: respond is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The callback in the validate function returns a type error: respond is not a function when trying to return the results of the evaluation. But when I try to throw an exception using new feature of Mongoose 5, I am able to pass the error on to my controller route successfully. Why is this happening?

```
  const alumni = module.exports = mongoose.model('alumni', Alumni);**strong text**

  Alumni.path('email').validate(function(value,respond){
  return alumni.findOne({email:value}, function(err, result){ 
  respond(result === null)                  
  })

  return true 
  }, 'email address exists');
```

Comment: The error is not throwed by Mongoose, its Node itself. `respond` is not a function and you are calling it as a function

Comment: how then do i retrieve the value of my function ?

Comment: I dont find any `validate()` function returning two arguments. Just error if there is validation error. Can you show any reference?

Comment: http://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/06/async-unique-validation-with-expressjs-and-mongoose/

Comment: example under async custom validator. The validator function needs to return a boolean that is handled through the callback. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: Validate() takes two arguments, a function and a callback. Callbacks are necessary where there is a nested function within the validation function which will return the boolean result.